# Why methods in Observable class are synchronized?

Tags: java, timer

Why are the methods in the Observable class are synchronized?

```
public synchronized void deleteObserver(Observer o) {
        obs.removeElement(o);
    }
```

Comment: To make an instance of the class thread-safe. Specifically, to properly synchronize access to the `obs` _and_ `changed` fields. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, obs is a vector which is supposed to be thread safe already, why do we need to make to thread safe again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you a definitive answer regarding *why* `Observable` is implemented the way it is, but I can explain the effect.

While `Vector` is a synchronized collection, it isn't synchronized while *iterating*. This is similar to the wrappers returned by the `Collections.synchronizedXXX` methods. In order to safely iterate a `Vector` in a concurrent context you need external synchronization. They accomplish this by using `synchronized` methods. But if you look at `notifyObservers` you'll see that the method isn't synchronized. However, if you look at the body of `notifyObservers` you'll see a `synchronized(this) {}` block. They do it this way because only part of the method body needs to be executed while holding the lock. If you're not aware, a `synchronized` instance method is the same as using `synchronized(this) {}` for the whole method.

The other effect caused by using `synchronized` methods is that both the `obs` field and the `changed` field are guarded by the same lock. This keeps the state between those two fields consistent in a multi-threaded environment. Why they chose the enclosing instance as the lock, I have no idea, but that's what they did.

Note that, as near as I can tell, the `Observable` class gives no guarantees regarding thread-safety in its documentation. This means the fact that it is thread-safe is an implementation detail.

Also note that `Observable` has been deprecated since Java 9.

Answer (score 1):

`Observable` is intended to be a very thread-safe class; it manipulates shared data 'atomically', meaning that only one thread can access it at a time. The `synchronized` keyword forces each interacting thread to access the `Observable` instance's data atomically.

> `synchronized` methods enable a simple strategy for preventing thread interference and memory consistency errors: if an object is visible to more than one thread, all reads or writes to that object's variables are done through synchronized methods.

Note that some methods, such as `notifyObservers()`, are not `synchronized`. This is because they do not directly affect the instance data of the `Observable`.

Read [this writeup](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-safety) if you want to learn more about thread-safety.